# dot product and addition of numpy arrays and vectors

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector

consider the following MWE:

```
import numpy as np

def create_weight_matrix(nrows, ncols):
    """Create a weight matrix with normally distributed random elements."""
    return np.random.default_rng().normal(loc=0, scale=1/(nrows*ncols), size=(nrows, ncols))

def create_bias_vector(length):
    """Create a bias vector with normally distributed random elements."""
    return create_weight_matrix(length,1)



if __name__ == "__main__":

    num_samples = 100
    num_features = 5

    W = create_weight_matrix(4, num_features)
    b = create_bias_vector(4)

    x = np.random.rand(num_samples, num_features)

    y = W.dot(x[1])
    print(y.shape)

    t = y + b
    print(t.shape)
```

The intermediate variable `y` is computed correctly as the dot product of `W` and `x[1]` and the output is a vector of the form `[ 0.06678158  0.02322523  0.09542323 -0.05746891]`. I try then to add vector `b` and i would expect this is performed element wise, but for some reason the code adds all elements of `b` to all elements of `y` creating a 4x4 matrix at the end instead of 4x1 vector. What am I missing here?

Comment: `b` has a shape `(4, 1)` (a column-vector) and `y` has a shape `(4,)` (a row vector). When you add them together, they get broadcasted into `(4, 4)` https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Comment: @pho , thanks. So  how could I achieve that b and y are compatible so that the result is an (4,1) vector?

Comment: Why are you using `x[1]` and not `x[0]` or even `x`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`b` has a shape `(4, 1)` (a column-vector) and `y` has a shape `(4,)` (a row vector). When you add them together, they get [broadcasted](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) into an array of shape `(4, 4)`. You can avoid this by explicitly reshaping one of the vectors to the same shape as the other.

For a column vector of shape `(4, 1)`, use any of the following lines:

```
t = b + y.reshape(b.shape)
t = b + y[:, None]
```

<sup>`y[:, None]` [adds a new axis](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html#numpy.newaxis) to the 1d array</sup>

or, for a row vector of shape `(4,)`:

```
t = b.reshape(y.shape) + y 
t = b.squeeze() + y
```

Comment: Congrats for python gold badge:)